# Angular 6 "Workspace needs to be loaded before it is used." when trying to generate a new Component

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular6

when I create asp.net core project with angular dotnet new command does not add an angular.json file (angular 6) to the project and therefor we are not able to use angular cli. If i add angular.json file manually the project give the exception below!?

```
Workspace needs to be loaded before it is used. Error: Workspace needs to be loaded before it is used. at Workspace._assertLoaded (D:\NetAngular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\workspace\workspace.js:59:19) at Workspace.getProjectByPath (D:\NetAngular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\workspace\workspace.js:103:14) at Object.getPackageManager (D:\NetAngular\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\config.js:97:35) at UpdateCommand.runSchematic (D:\NetAngular\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\schematic-command.js:74:38) at UpdateCommand.<anonymous> (D:\NetAngular\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\update.js:70:25) at Generator.next (<anonymous>) at D:\NetAngular\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\update.js:7:71 at new Promise (<anonymous>) at __awaiter (D:\NetAngular\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\update.js:3:12) at UpdateCommand.run (D:\NetAngular\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\update.js:69:16)
```

Comment: are you in angular project directory?

Comment: yes sure on the root of the project since i have opened the project from command line

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EUREKA.............

dotnet new angular comman does not create an angular.json file on the root of the application. in some sites they say that after using

```
npm install --save--dev @angular/cli@latest
```

command use

```
npm update @angular/cli
```

which will migrate you angular-cli.json file to angular.json file!!! but the point here there is no angular-cli.json file nor angular.json.

I solved the problem by creating my own angular.json file as bellow (you may change vega with your project name)

```
 {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "vega": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "ClientApp",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "ClientApp/dist/vega"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [{
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
              }],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

after that i was able to use angular cli command and create components and services.

> Code to be Happy

Answer (score 11):

I was getting the same error, and yes angular.json was making the problem.
This error can occur while you are adding the external css path manually. I had missed the comma while referencing bootstrap css.

While adding the custom CSS in style array, I missed the comma(,)

**Error File:**

If you see below code comma is missing after
 "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.css".

```
"styles": [
          "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.css"
          "src/styles.css"

        ]
```

**Solution:**  Comma added

```
"styles": [
          "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"

        ]
```

[image: CLI error]

Comment: Thank you. Nice to have a different solution

Comment: Thanks @MuhanadY.. Could you confirm, If your error can be resolved with this?

Comment: That was not the main error of my issue. I solve it as I discriped above . Thanks again for sharing

Answer (score 9):

Same error. Tried uninstall, reinstall and upgrade, ng still reported this error information.

After removed an empty ~/.angular-config.json file, everything is working well again.

Answer (score 3):

It is confirmed that you have made some changes in angular.json. if you have a syntax problem in your angular.json file there this error happens. I would say this is unexpected behavior and should be changed to say there is a syntax problem in the file instead.

[Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10757)

Comment: This was my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After added comma after `buildOptimizer:true`, It is working fine.

```
"configurations": {
        "production": {
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true //I missed to put comma here...
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I did change my angular.json file, but I saw no errors. After double checking the commas and everything I saved it with encoding (UTF-8), then formatted the document (right click and Format Document), that removed 10 redundant lines. After that I could run the angular cli update, and the commands as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar error:

"An unhandled exception occurred: Workspace config file cannot be loaded: /*/*/Projects/*/*/project/angular.json
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(**scripts**).
See "/private/var/folders/f8/cq9wj86n3gbfj8h64f8jlx2m0000gn/T/ng-5TCBsc/angular-errors.log" for further details."

It was because of extra '**scripts**' key I added in angular.json earlier. Removed that and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error,This error can occur while:

1. it may be from the `@angular/cli` version.
2. missed the `comma` char at end of line in `angular.json` or `tsconfig.json`.
3. `unicode` of the `angular.json` or `tsconfig.json` file (will be `UTF-8`).
4. would have existed `comment` line at the `angular.json` or `tsconfig.json`. (in my case, there was comment line at `tsconfig.json`).

> ```
> {
>
>   "compileOnSave": false,
>   "compilerOptions": {
>     "baseUrl": "./",
>     //"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc", // comment line caused the error. I removed this line
>     "outDir": "../content/ManagmentJob",
>     "sourceMap": true,
>     "declaration": false,
>     "module": "es2015",
>     "moduleResolution": "node",
>     "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
>     "experimentalDecorators": true,
>     "target": "es5",
>     "typeRoots": [
>       "node_modules/@types"
>     ],
>     ...
> }
> ```