# Angular on ng new Service: "Workspace needs to be loaded befor it is used "

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to add pusher.js into my angular.json file. 
But when I do it and want to create a new service following error shows up:
Error: Workspace needs to be loaded before it is used.
Does somebody now how to solve this?

I tried to update the angular cli but nothing worked...
Here's my angular.json file:

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "iotbrowser": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src/main/webapp",
            "projectType": "application",
            "architect": {}
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "iotbrowser",
    "cli": {
        "packageManager": "npm"
    },
    "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
            "inlineStyle": true,
            "inlineTemplate": false,
            "spec": false,
            "prefix": "jhi",
            "styleExt": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
            "spec": false,
            "prefix": "jhi"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:guard": {
            "spec": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
            "spec": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:service": {
            "spec": false
        }
    },
    "scripts":[
        "../node_modules/pusher-js/dist/web/pusher.min.js"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I beleive that you are target wrong path since angular.json are in same level of node_modules folder. So you need to check the node_modules folder path are correct in your angular.json.

Below is the issue I notice

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "iotbrowser": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src/main/webapp",
            "projectType": "application",
            "architect": {}
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "iotbrowser",
    "cli": {
        "packageManager": "npm"
    },
    "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
            "inlineStyle": true,
            "inlineTemplate": false,
            "spec": false,
            "prefix": "jhi",
            "styleExt": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
            "spec": false,
            "prefix": "jhi"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:guard": {
            "spec": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
            "spec": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:service": {
            "spec": false
        }
    },
    "scripts":[
        "./node_modules/pusher-js/dist/web/pusher.min.js" // this one change to ./
    ]
}
```

There are related issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10757) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50269399/angular-6-workspace-needs-to-be-loaded-before-it-is-used-when-trying-to-gener) so you can check it out